# Include text in file without <?php ?> tags [file_get_contents]

Tags: php

I have noobish question for you guys. I'm making my private sandboxie where you can test your code. So for now what I'm making is that you write the code, code is executed and you can see the result BUT i want the code you written in the textbox.

Now the problem is, I want that text from .php file to be shown without  tags. I might be idiot but I just don't remember how to do it.

so actually code is like

```
            if($_GET['f']){
                echo file_get_contents("files/".$_GET['f'].".php");
            }else{
                echo "echo \"Hello world\";";
            }
```

if you don't understand what I want I can post more info etc but I think its obvious:)

Comment: You're making a server where people can submit code and you'll execute it on your server?  Be _very_ careful.

Comment: no no, its for my private use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
<?php 
echo str_replace(array('<?php', '?>'), '', file_Get_contents('file.php'));
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The `include` function :)

```
include("files/" . $_GET['f'] . ".php");
```

But! Never read a file directly from `$_GET`. Someone could put in `../../sensitiveinformation.txt` or something.

Comment: So what, you just want to str_replace `<?php` with nothing?

Comment: exactly, just want to remove `<?php` tags out of it

Answer (score 0):

Use `include();` and `require();` would help you include the file. Use [`eval();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute the code.

To see the actual source of the file and strip the `<?php` `?>` tags do this

```
   $file = file_get_contents('time.php');
    $ll = array('<?php','?>');

    echo str_replace($ll, "", $file);
```